# Optimal stopping time problem

Tags: stochastic-processes, stopping-times

I'm trying to solve a problem:
$$
\sup_{0 \leq \tau \leq 1} E W_{\tau - \varepsilon},
$$
where $W$ is a Wiener process and $\varepsilon$ is a fixed real number.

I've tried to approximate a Wiener process by a random walk, but I couldn't get any good results (maybe, I missed something and that's a good idea). So, what think you about that problem? Any ideas, hints, or even a solution

Comment: isn't the Wiener process a martingale?  I think it should be 0 for any time $\tau$

Comment: No, it holds only if $ \varepsilon = 0. $